# Why does this output print a blank file?

Tags: java, file-io

This little code snippet should output a file that contains text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Path gabblePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/AlterionX/Documents/"
                 + "NetBeansProjects/File Creator, Function Example/src/file/"
                 + "gabble.txt");
        Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String total = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(total);
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(gabblePath, cs);
        writer.write(total);
        System.out.println("total printed");
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Instead, it creates and returns a blank file. It runs successfully, and all the other stuff, it just creates a blank file.

Should I be closing the scanner or is it something else?

EDIT
I took out the scanner and changed it to an actual string, still didn't work.

Comment: I might be off here - but try flushing it.

Comment: yeah, call `flush` or `close` on `writer` instance

Comment: close the `BufferedWriter` via `writer.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the `Writer` and make sure you do it unconditionally (i.e. a finally block).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try{
        Path gabblePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/AlterionX/Documents/"
                 + "NetBeansProjects/File Creator, Function Example/src/file/"
                 + "gabble.txt");
        Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String total = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(total);
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(gabblePath, cs);
        writer.write(total);
        System.out.println("total printed");
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I think there is a cleaner way to handle the try/catch within the finally cleanup code in Java 7 or 8, but I haven't worked with it yet so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the FileWriter class instead.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(gabblePath);

fw.write(total);
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

You just need the path to your output file and the contents.